# Ubuntu boot loader is not working

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop having one 32Gb SSD(GPT) where i have installed windows 10 and other 500Gb HDD(MBR) and further my HDD is divided into 4 partitions where in 3 partitions my data is stored and the last is unallocated for installing ubuntu 20.04. when i installing Ubuntu it moves smoothly no error occur but after completing installation when i restart my system it shows a message "1.98525] usbhid 1-1.3:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint " and then after few seconds the screen appears with "GNU GRUB version 2.04
minimal BASH-like line editing is supported......device or file completion ". Kindly give some good solution i have tried alot from google but haven't work me

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? Best to only use same boot mode for Ubuntu as boot mode for Windows. But UEFI should also be on gpt partitioned drive, with Windows it is required. If installing in BIOS mode you have to use Something Else and install grub to HDD's MBR. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

boot from your Ubuntu live CD/ USB and follow instructions given in link of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page. Follow the second option:

**install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```

And follow **Recommended repair** for more detail.

You can also refer to website of [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)